# NodeJS Server External Access

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, nodes, node-modules

I am writing to ask what is causing the behavior of my NodeJS application. So, I am wanting to allow access to external connections to the server while running the application off of my computer.

NodeJS app.js

```
server.listen(3000, 'device-IPv4 address');
```

Then I am port forwarding off of my router on port 3000 just fine.

So when I access the server via http://device-IPv4:3000, things work perfectly fine as expected.

But when I access the server via http://PublicIP:3000, it technically loads, however, it often stalls by waiting for a connection giving the error:

"This site can't be reached. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT."

But if it tries to connect enough times, it eventually loads seemingly randomly.

I would think that this set up would work just fine, so I cannot figure what would be causing that sort of behavior. What all could it be? If you need more info, just ask, and I can provide. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What is your network setup?  Do you have something forwarding ports from your public IP to this private IP?

Comment: @Brad How would I go about doing something like that? I thought that I had done something similar to my current set up a few years ago, and it had worked just fine, but perhaps I am just missing something. Is there a better solution to what I am trying to achieve than what I am currently doing? Alternatively, if I were to forward ports from public IP to private IP, how would I go about doing something like that?

Comment: How should we know, you didn't explain what your network setup is yet.  Is this some server somewhere?  Your computer at home?  What's in between it and the internet?

Comment: @Brad My server is literally just running on my computer here at my house. My router is between my computer and the internet lol

Comment: Alright, so assuming you have a typical home router running NAT, you need to login to that router's control panel and set up a forwarded port to your computer.  The specifics for how to do this vary from router to router.

Comment: @Brad I do have a port forwarded already! It is currently open on my public IP address on the specific port (TCP/UDP). That is what I would want, correct? I guess that's why I am confused why it's behaving the way it is. The webpage on the server is actually loading, but it times out sometimes and eventually loads after so many connection attempts which is odd to me.

Comment: Something is apparently wrong with some element of the path from your router to the server.  It could be something not quite right with the port forwarding, something with your firewall, something with your local LAN between the router and the PC the server is on, power management options on your server computer, etc...  It's really hard for us to know without any ability to debug the issue ourselves.